# Calculating SMD

Tags: meta-analysis

Is it possible to calculate SMD when the only data reported is the mean scores before and at end of study, for intervention and control groups, along with significance levels?

This is how the data for the outcome I'm interested in is given in the paper. I am trying to calculate a common rubric for effect size.

```
                          Mean ± SD             Significance

                      Before      After


                    75.167.13*  66.326.55         p< 0.05
```

Comment: If by SMD you mean (Strictly) Standardized Mean Difference then you also need variances.

Comment: The study only reports SD for some outcomes (and not the ones I'm interested in) - I did think it wasn't possible to calculate the SMD without them - thank-you for helping.

Comment: Would there be any other way of calculating effect size with that data alone - I can't see any way but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: Can you include a table in your question with all the available data?

Comment: Have now edited question with data

Comment: Please fix the format, it hasn't rendered well. Also, it this really all that you have available?

Comment: This is the only data provided for the outcome i am interested in for this study.

Comment: If this is all that is available then you are proverbially screwed. Couple of points: 1) you should fix the numbers, what do the dots represent? Dots should be used for decimals. 2) Can you contact the authors to ask for information? 3) If all else fails and there is no way to get additional information AND you really need to solve this, you could get a rough estimate using simulations by guessing the SD's.

Comment: Thank-you - I wasn't sure what the extra dots meant - that is how they are presented in the table.

Comment: The caption promises that there are means and standard deviations, possibly they have just left out the space and it should read 75.16 space 7.13. Does that make sense in the context of other values you have?

Comment: Yes, I have decided it was probably a mistype within the paper.